# Sanitize HTML Content before using wp_remote_post

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a WordPress plugin, which will gather post's information such as post title, post content and send to 3rd party application to do some analysis.

Basically will store post title and post content into array, encode the array into JSON format and send to 3rd party application via `wp_remote_post`. I'm facing challenge in the post content which may containing some html tag and ruin my JSON data.

What should I do to prevent the post content breaking my JSON data? Should I sanitize it or in other way?

Example code as below:

```
$args = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content()
);

$json = json_encode($args);

wp_remote_post( 'http://dummydomain.com/', array(
    'body' => array(
        'data' => $args
    )
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to pass additional flags to json_encode, to notify it that your code can contains HTML tags. Passing this two flags should be enough:

> JSON_HEX_TAG - All < and > are converted to \u003C and \u003E. Available since PHP 5.3.0.
>   JSON_HEX_QUOT - All " are converted to \u0022. Available since PHP 5.3.0.

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Your code could look like this:

```
$args = array(
    'title' => get_the_title(),
    'content' => get_the_content()
);

$json = json_encode($args, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_QUOT);

wp_remote_post( 'http://dummydomain.com/', array(
    'body' => array(
        'data' => $json
    )
) );
```